# Using generic type in Struct & Function Block

Tags: generics, struct, plc, st, twincat

I would like to create a type-generic `STRUCT` and a paired `Function Block` that accept and return variables of a generic type (assumed `ANY_NUM`).

This is desired to condense many existing `STRUCT` and `FB` pairs in the same format using generic number types [probably belonging to the `ANY_NUM` type](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/9007201784167563.html&id=2058661990612177947) into a single generic pair.

In C++, the Generic Structure would be accomplished with a `Template Class`, but I cannot find a similar structure in Structured Text.

I tried the generic Function Block [on Beckhoff's ANY/ANY_(TYPE) page](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/9007201784167563.html&id=2058661990612177947), however it quickly failed to `convert type 'LREAL' to type '__SYSTEM.AnyType'`.

**Question:**

To what extent can I accomplish this goal in Structured Text?

**EDIT:**

I mistakenly assumed that `ANY` is the only ST generic of relevance.
I have been directed to [type T_Arg](https://stefanhenneken.wordpress.com/2018/04/18/iec-61131-3-der-generische-datentyp-t_arg/) as a potentially viable candidate.

**Example Format of Attempt:**

Structure:

```
TYPE Bounded_Value:
STRUCT
    Value   : ANY_NUM;
    Min_    : ANY_NUM;
    Max_    : ANY_NUM;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

Function Block:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Bind_Value
VAR_IN_OUT
    value_struct: Bounded_Value;
END_VAR
```

(Implementation would bind `value_struct.Value` to between `value_struct.min_` and `value_struct.max_`)

Comment: `REAL` and `LREAL` are not `ANY_NUM`. Those have to be converted. From the perspective on math as we know it we consider it a number, but from perspective of data types, `INT` and `REAL` are different types.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov I do not understand what you mean. 
According to [the Beckhoff page on ANY](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/9007201784167563.html&id=2058661990612177947), ANY_NUM encompasses ANY_REAL and ANY_INT.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov Oh, you are meaning to express that ANY_NUM and LREAL are not equivalent types, as ANY_NUM is a struct containing the type, pointer, and size of a number, while REAL/LREAL/INT are the numbers themselves. Correct?

Comment: you are right. I missed it with ANY_INT. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I gleaned the solution to my problem from [Stefan Henneken's blog post on T_Arg](https://stefanhenneken.wordpress.com/2018/04/18/iec-61131-3-der-generische-datentyp-t_arg/).)*

The goal can be accomplished, but not particularly cleanly. There are two generic types (that I have found so far) that are applicable: `ANY_NUM` and `T_Arg`.

(I use `ANY_NUM` because it is most relevant to this example. `ANY`, `ANY_REAL`, or `ANY_INT` would also be reasonable options)

Both options have similar structures and function similarly. Each is a structure containing information on the stored variable: **its type, a pointer to it, and its size**.

Yet there are pros and cons to each. To fulfill this problem most accurately, we would use **`T_Arg`**.

Here is the difference:

### ANY / ANY_NUM / ETC

**Advantage:** Variable conversion to `ANY_NUM` is done [implicitly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) when a variable is assigned. The input variable needs no pre-conversion before being input into the function, cutting down on the size of code.

Furthermore, it only accepts variables belonging to its domain, so strings will not be used accidentally.

**Disadvantage:** `ANY_NUM` cannot be declared outside of a `VAR_INPUT` block and, in fact, provides this error message upon attempt:

```
Variables of type 'ANY_NUM' only allowed as input of functions.
```

Therefore `ANY_NUM` cannot be used as a `STRUCT` variable, even if that `STRUCT` is declared as an input to a function. This is why it cannot be used to solve this particular problem.

### T_Arg

**Advantage:** [`T_Arg`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibutilities/html/tcplclibutilities_t_arg.htm&id=) can be declared and used anywhere.

**Disadvantage:** `T_Arg` requires conversion functions for any expected variable type, e.g.:
[`F_INT()`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/9007199289993227.html&id=),`F_REAL()`,`F_DINT()`, etc.

Therefore type-checking needs to be performed before and after input.

### Example Solution

Unfortunately, a variable stored in `T_Arg` cannot be directly manipulated. It is necessary to move the stored variable to a temporary variable to use it. So `Value`, `Min_`, and `Max_` would each need conversion from type `T_Arg` into type `REAL`/`INT`/etc.

As we are trying to only use one `STRUCT`, `Value` would need to be converted again into T_Arg once `Bind_Value` finishes manipulating it.

In total, `Value` would be converted three times when instantiated and twice per call after.

**Structure:**

```
TYPE Bounded_Value:
STRUCT
    Value   : T_Arg;
    Min_    : T_Arg;
    Max_    : T_Arg;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

**Function Block:**

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Bind_Value
VAR_IN_OUT
    value_struct: Bounded_Value;
    // Other variable type declarations
END_VAR
VAR
    val_int     :   INT;
    max_int     :   INT;
    min_int     :   INT;
END_VAR
```

---

```
CASE (value_struct.Value.eType) OF
    E_ArgType.ARGTYPE_INT: // If the struct's Value's type is INT
        // Copy generic pointer information into typed pointer 
        MEMCPY(ADR(val_int), value_struct.Value.pData, value_struct.Value.cbLen);
        MEMCPY(ADR(max_int), value_struct.Max_.pData,  value_struct.Max_.cbLen);
        MEMCPY(ADR(min_int), value_struct.Min_.pData,  value_struct.Min_.cbLen);

        IF val_int > max_int THEN
            value_struct.Value.pData := value_struct.Max_.pData;
        ELSIF val_int < min_int THEN
            value_struct.Value.pData := value_struct.Min_.pData;
        END_IF
    // Other variable type handlings
END_CASE
```

**MAIN:**

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    val     : INT := -1; //Change this to test
    minim   : INT :=  0;
    maxim   : INT :=  5;
    newVal  : INT;
    bv      : Bounded_Value;
    bind    : Bind_Value;
END_VAR
```

---

```
// Convert INT variables to T_Arg in structure
bv.Value:= F_INT(val);
bv.Max_ := F_INT(maxim);
bv.Min_ := F_INT(minim);
// Bind_Value.value_struct := bv;
bind(value_struct := bv);
// Copy result to newVal
MEMCPY(ADR(newVal), bv.Value.pData, bv.Value.cbLen);
```

Comment: Did you try to use aliases? `TYPE MyType: T_Arg; END_TYPE` and then `VAR in: MyType; END_VAR`?

Comment: I did not, why do you ask? (I do not see how replacing `T_Arg` would condense code size, as I would still have to perform type conversion.)

Answer (score 3):

I've recently investigated this (ANY-type) in TwinCAT. What you basically need to do is to convert every byte that the ANY-pointer points to into a LREAL (which you know according to IEC61131-3 will always be 8bytes). The ANY type holds information on what type it points to, so you will know when it is a LREAL by parsing the structure of data the ANY-pointer points to. Please read my complete investigation on my blog: [The wonders of ANY](http://alltwincat.com/2018/03/21/the-wonders-of-any/)

Comment: Your blog does clear up some confusion I had regarding ANY_TYPE's use in functions, However, neither your blog nor [Stefan Henneken's blog on T_Arg](https://stefanhenneken.wordpress.com/2018/04/18/iec-61131-3-der-generische-datentyp-t_arg/) clear up use of these variables in a structure.

Comment: I suppose I could attempt to use a Function Block or Program to load values into each STRUCT, but that just creates more work and consumes far more space than just having a STRUCT for each variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a generic type with the help of a Function Block and a Union.
Let's say you define a Union with all your DUTs and POUs:

```
TYPE GenericType :
UNION
    generic : PVOID;
    bBool   : REFERENCE TO BOOL;
    nInt    : REFERENCE TO INT;
    nUint   : REFERENCE TO UINT;
    nUdint  : REFERENCE TO UDINT;
    fReal   : REFERENCE TO REAL;
    fLreal  : REFERENCE TO LREAL;
    fbTest  : REFERENCE TO FB_Test;
END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

Then you create a special Function Block:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Generic
VAR_INPUT
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
END_VAR
VAR
    uGenericType : GenericType;
END_VAR
```

And a Property that gets and sets a PVOID:

```
PROPERTY PUBLIC generic : PVOID
```

The getter:

```
generic := uGenericType.generic;
```

The setter:

```
uGenericType.generic := generic;
```

You also need Properties in order to retrieve your type later:

[Image of the FB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZsCq.png)

An example of the getBool setter could be:

```
IF uGenericType.generic = 0 
THEN
    RETURN;
ELSE
    getBool := uGenericType.bBool;
END_IF
```

Now you create the FB that will make use of the generic type:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Container
VAR_INPUT

    myGenericType       : Generic;
    nContainerOption    : INT;

END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
END_VAR
VAR

    testInt             : INT;
    testBool            : BOOL;
    testFB              : FB_Test;

END_VAR
```

---

```
CASE nContainerOption OF

    1:
        testInt := myGenericType.getInt;

    2:
        testFB := myGenericType.getFbTest;

    3:
        testBool := myGenericType.getBool;

END_CASE
```

The call could be like this:

```
fbContainer.myGenericType.generic := ADR(testInteger);
...
fbContainer(nContainerOption := 1);
```

Another approach is to extend our FBs with the Generic FB.
We need to do some modifications to the Generic FB and to the GenericType Union though:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK Generic
VAR_INPUT
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
END_VAR
VAR
    uGenericType    : GenericType;
    bInit           : BOOL;
END_VAR
```

---

```
IF NOT bInit THEN
 uGenericType.generic := ADR(THIS^);
 bInit := TRUE;
END_IF
```

---

```
TYPE GenericType :
UNION
    generic : PVOID;

    //Add the pointer of the FB you want to extend
    pAxis   : POINTER TO FB_Axis;

    bBool   : REFERENCE TO BOOL;
    nInt    : REFERENCE TO INT;
    nUint   : REFERENCE TO UINT;
    nUdint  : REFERENCE TO UDINT;
    fReal   : REFERENCE TO REAL;
    fLreal  : REFERENCE TO LREAL;
    fbTest  : REFERENCE TO FB_Test;

END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

The extended FB:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Axis EXTENDS Generic
VAR_INPUT
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
END_VAR
VAR
    fPosition : LREAL;
END_VAR
```

And now the call of our container as before:

```
fbContainer.myGenericType := fbAxis;
```

in FB_Container you could call the axis as follows:

```
IF myGenericType.getPointerFbAxis <> 0 
THEN
    position := myGenericType.getPointerFbAxis^.fPosition;
END_IF
```